# How to solve'System.Data.Entity.Database.DefaultConnectionFactory' is obsolete?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Using Asp.Net MVC at the following line:

```
Database.DefaultConnectionFactory = new SqlCeConnectionFactory("System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0");
```

I get error message:

```
Warning as Error: 'System.Data.Entity.Database.DefaultConnectionFactory' is obsolete: 'The default connection factory should be set in the config file or using the DbConfiguration class. (See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260883)'
```

How to rewrite it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied from msdn link

```
[ObsoleteAttribute("The default connection factory should be set in the config file or using the  DbConfiguration class. (See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260883)")]
public static IDbConnectionFactory DefaultConnectionFactory { get; set; }
```

Here is the link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.defaultconnectionfactory(v=vs.113).aspx

one more link it suggests
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260883

Answer (score 1):

if you want to set `DefaultConnectionFactory` using config file then you can follow this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556606.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a class inheriting from System.Data.Entity.DbConfiguration to the assembly where your DbContext class resides.

In the constructor of the class you add the call:
 SetDefaultConnectionFactory(new SqlCeConnectionFactory("System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"));